# Rollback to earlier master

Tags: git

My git repo started on master, with the intention of adding Facebook logins to a web site. As an experiment, I added Google logins, in a branch called `GOOGLE_AUTH`. Then I continued on master with Facebook logins, but I have made an about turn on Facebook, and wish to revert `master` to just before I branched `GOOGLE_AUTH`, but preserve `GOOGLE_AUTH`. That is not too important, as I had only enabled Goolge Auth, ID and secret, but I have changed several classes since adding Facebook auth to the master, which as mistakenly intended. I would now like to be on `master`, with an in-tacked `GOOGLE_AUTH` branch, but without any facebook changes.

Is this possible without manual rollback of all changed files since `GOOGLE_AUTH`?

Comment: Did you push these branches to remote repo or just work locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# find the split commit (junction) when you first go out with the GOOGLE_AUTH branch
git log --graph --decorate

# change your filesystem state to the prev state (what you find above) 
git checkout <COMMIT_SHA> # of the upper commit

# remove the master branch 'pointer'
git branch -d master # delete master

# create new branch master 'pointer' in the same commit you found earlier
git checkout -b master
```

Comment: Thanks, a most educating answer. Are there any implications if I have pushed to the remote very often, every 2 or 3 commits, and definitely when I create a new branch.

Comment: If it helped you, I'll appreciate if you can accept is as answer & upvote for my reputation. Regarding your second question: I'm pushing each 2-3 commits for backup purpose (if my computer will burn ;-) ). Commit are the most important thing you want to backup. Branche is only pointer to some commit - you can always delete this pointer and create a new one to each commit that you'll like..

Answer (score 0):

You can `git checkout [commit]` to get the state of the master branch on that specific point in time and then commit. Since your `GOOGLE_AUTH` is on a separate branch, it won't be affected. After you finish your google auth feature, merge it to the master branch.

Also, you should take a look at git flow technique: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/